# how do i test cookie expiry in rails rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, rspec

There is a lot of confusion about setting cookies in rspec
http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/dir/controller-specs/file/cookies

in your controller, normally you can write

```
cookies['transaction_code'] = { :expires => 300.seconds.from_now, :value => c }
```

but in rspec i can only write

```
request.cookies['transaction_code'] = transaction_code
```

if i say

```
request.cookies['transaction_code'] = { :expires => 300.seconds.from_now, :value => c }
```

i get the hash back as value of cookies['transaction_code'] in my controller.

Now my question is: how do i set/test cookie expiry then in an rspec controller test example?

UPDATE: On seconds thought: What i mean is: how do i test if the controller is reacts to an expired cookie as expected, but in fact an expired cookie is just like no cookie if i trust cookie implementation, which i should do, so after all maybe my question makes no sense. If this is the case, i need to test if (another) controller action sets an expiring cookie correctly, but how do i do it if cookies['transaction_code'] in the test only gives the value back?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Browsers [do not send cookie attributes back to the server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_attributes). This is why you can only send the key-value pair to the action.

Since you can assume that Rails, Rack and browsers do the right thing with the arguments, all you really need to test is the arguments your code is passing to the `CookieJar`.

To test that expiry is being set properly *in the controller setting the cookie*, you could stub out the `#cookies` method and make sure the right settings are being passed to it.

```
# app/controllers/widget_controller.rb
...
def index
    cookies[:expiring_cookie] = { :value   => 'All that we see or seem...', 
                                  :expires => 1.hour.from_now }
end
...

# spec/controllers/widget_controller_spec.rb
...
it "sets the cookie" do
  get :index
  response.cookies['expiring_cookie'].should eq('All that we see or seem...')
                                               # is but a dream within a dream.
                                               #                - Edgar Allan Poe
end

it "sets the cookie expiration" do
  stub_cookie_jar = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
  controller.stub(:cookies) { stub_cookie_jar }

  get :index
  expiring_cookie = stub_cookie_jar['expiring_cookie']
  expiring_cookie[:expires].to_i.should be_within(1).of(1.hour.from_now.to_i)
end
...
```

Testing much more than this is boiling the ocean. At some point, you have to assume that the stack you are sitting on (e.g., Rails, Rack, the web server, TCP/IP, OS, web browsers, etc) works properly and focus on the code you control.

Comment: nice one kro, i accept your answer, i am not sure about stubbing cookiestore, to mention the obvious Access to the cookie jar is indifferent to the use of symbols or strings as keys unlike your hash stub. In general, i feel uneasy stubbing what is part of the framework. Also, is something like expiring_cookie[:expires].to_i.should be_within(1).of(1.hour.from_now.to_i) the best practice to test dynamic time settings?

Comment: No, I'd probably do something different with the matcher for the `DateTime` in the actual spec. My goal was to provide something that would pass as an illustration, since `==` won't.

Comment: As for your indifferent access issue; this is easily fixed by using `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` instead of a stdlib `Hash`. I updated the example code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I came from the future with this:

```
  it 'sets the cookie expiration' do
    stub_cookie_jar = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
    allow(controller).to receive(:cookies).and_return(stub_cookie_jar)
    get :index
    expiracy_date = stub_cookie_jar[:expires]
    expect(expiracy_date).to be_between(1.hour.from_now - 1.minutes, 
                                        1.hour.from_now)
  end
```

Comment: I was having problems with RSpec's built-in cookie support, switched to this and it all worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Another option using [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop):

```
Timecop.freeze(Time.now)

expect(controller.send(:cookies)).to receive(:[]=).with('cookie_name',
  value:   'whatever',
  expires: 1.hour.from_now
)

get :index
```

Answer (score 0):

set request.cookies['transaction_code'] as a CGI::Cookie in your spec. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI/Cookie.html#M000169

Comment: Even if you pass in a `CGI::Cookie` object to `request.cookies` (prior to invoking the action) the `response.cookies` hash still only returns a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check several cookie attributes at once, inspect the Set-Cookie header, something like this:

```
it 'expires cookie in 15 minutes' do
  travel_to(Date.new(2016, 10, 25))
  post 'favorites', params: { flavor: 'chocolate' }
  travel_back

  details = 'favorite=chocolate; path=/; expires=Tue, 25 Oct 2016 07:15:00 GMT; HttpOnly'
  expect(response.header['Set-Cookie']).to eq details
end
```

This is a bit brittle, in that other, non-critical attributes of the cookie may break this string. But it does keep you out of Rails internals, and lets you check several attributes at once.

A better way is to match just one attribute at a time, this is a much more robust method that is not so vulnerable to changes in how the Set-Cookie string is constructed, or what other attributes you might add to the cookie in the future:

```
  expect(response.header['Set-Cookie']).to match(
    /favorite=chocolate.*; expires=Tue, 25 Oct 2016 07:15:00 GMT/
  )
```