# Is there any way to check if rails set permanent cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using TestUnit and I want to test the remember me functionality (when user login).

the cookies variable(and also require/response .cookies) contain only the cookie value without the expire time.

Rails somehow tell the web-browser when the cookie should be expire, so I assume there must be a way to check the cookie expire time.

### EDIT

```
test "set permanent cookie" do
  post :create, email: 'email', password: 'password', remember_me: true
  # cookies[:auth_token] = random_string
  # @request.cookies[:auth_token] = also_random_string
  # @response.cookies[:auth_token] = also_random_string
end
```

the problem is that I can get only the values of the cookies and not the hash that contain the expire time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, the `cookies` Hash only contains the values, not the expiration times, when you inspect it after your `post` call (this has been the behavior since at least Rails 2.3).

You have two options:

First, you could inspect the `response.headers["Set-Cookie"]` item instead. It will include the expiration time in there. However, the `Set-Cookie` value is just a single string, which you would need to then parse. For example, `cookies["foo"] = {:value => "bar", :expires => Time.now + 10.years }` would give you:

```
response.headers["Set-Cookie"]
# => "foo=bar; path=/; expires=Mon, 16-Aug-2021 21:54:30 GMT"
```

The other option (taken from [This Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492659/how-do-i-test-cookie-expiry-in-rails-rspec)), would be to stub the cookie jar and make sure it is sent an `expires` value:

```
stub_cookie_jar = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
controller.stub(:cookies) { stub_cookie_jar }
post :create, email: 'email', password: 'password', remember_me: true
expiring_cookie = stub_cookie_jar['expiring_cookie']
expiring_cookie[:expires].to_i.should be_within(1).of(1.hour.from_now.to_i)
```

Comment: That's not what I asked, I know how to set cookie with expire time. I don't know how to access the expire time via my functionality tests.

Comment: How do you write test to the code line you just wrote to be sure it's won't be session expire

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you're trying to access the cookie now?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - see my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the solutions presented or linked in @DylanMarkow's answer working, so here is how I tested that a "permanent" cookie was being set when a Remember Me checkbox was checked (the tests are influenced/blatantly copied from the [Test::Unit tests that DHH made in the commit that added `cookies.permanent` to Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0200e20f148c96afceeebc4da7b5985643f9f707#L2R149)).

Tests use [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) and [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

**spec/requests/authentication_requests_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication Requests" do
  # ...
  describe "authorization" do
    # ...
    describe "cookies" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      subject { response.headers["Set-Cookie"] }

      context "when remember me is set" do
        before { sign_in_request(user) }
        it { should =~ %r(.+expires.+#{20.years.from_now.year}) }
      end

      context "when remember me is not set" do
        before { sign_in_request(user, remember_me: false) }
        it { should_not =~ %r(expires) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/utilities.rb**

```
def sign_in_request(user, remember_me: "true")
  post session_path(
    session: {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      remember_me: remember_me
    }
  )
end
```

App code snippets below use [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), [Haml](http://haml.info/), [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html), and [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) syntax:

**app/views/sessions/new.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for :session, url: session_path, html: {class: 'form-vertical' } do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  .checkbox
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false do
      = check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, true
      = label_tag :remember_me
  = f.submit t('.signin'), class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                                params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      flash[:success] = t('flash.successful_signin')
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = t('flash.invalid_credentials')
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  # ...
  before_create :generate_authentication_token

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    find_by_email(email).try(:authenticate, password)
  end

  private

    def generate_authentication_token
      begin
        self.authentication_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(authentication_token: self.authentication_token)
    end
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  private

    # A cookie that does not have an expiry will automatically be expired by
    # the browser when browser's session is finished.
    # cookies.permanent sets the expiry to 20 years
    # Booleans seem to get passed from forms as strings
    def sign_in(user)
      if remember_me
        cookies.permanent[:authentication_token] = user.authentication_token
      else
        cookies[:authentication_token] = user.authentication_token
      end
      self.current_user = user
    end
    helper_method :sign_in

    def remember_me
      params[:session].try(:[], :remember_me) == "true" ||
        params[:remember_me] == "true"
    end
    # ...
end
```